# Manually disposing SqlDbConnection causes "internal .net framework provider error 1"

Tags: c#, sql-server, async-await

I'm writing a "data access layer" style library. It's just a C# library that will contain a bunch of functions that execute SQL queries. The library also provides a custom "session" object that acts as my unit of work container and manages my `SqlDbConnection`.

This session class of mine implements `IDisposable` and is intended to be used within a `using` block. In this same session class, the constructor creates a `SqlDbConnection` and opens the connection. The connection is not closed until the `Dispose` method of my session class is called.

Within my session class' `Dispose` method, I call the `Dispose` method of the `SqlDbConnection`. Sometimes, not every time, I get a low level error that only shows the following message ...

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Internal .Net Framework Data
>   Provider error 1.'

With the provided stack trace ...

```
 at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.PrePush(Object expectedOwner)
 at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.PutObject(DbConnectionInternal obj, Object owningObject)
 at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.CloseConnection(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.CloseInnerConnection()
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Close()
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
 at System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose()
 at Agent.Data.AgentSession.Dispose(Boolean disposeManagedResources)
 at Agent.Data.AgentSession.Finalize()
```

At the bottom of the stack trace, you can see my `AgentSession` class, which is the "session" class, unit of work class, that I described above. You can see where I have my `Dispose` function, and then from which you can see I call the `SqlConnection`'s `Dispose`.

This issue exists whether I call `Dispose` or `Close` on `SqlConnection`.

I've read that this could be due to me having a `SqlDbReader` open while trying to close the connection. All of my readers are within `using` blocks. I've also never encountered this issue, with readers and connections, in my 10 years of using C# and `SqlConnection`.

Now, the only thing that I'm doing new in this project that I've never done in past projects is make extensive use of `async` and `await`. I'm using all Async versions of the SQL related methods. All of my readers use Async method, etc.

Does anybody know what could be causing this or how I can further debug this?

This causes Visual Studio 2017 to go into "break mode" when this occurs, which means that the only information I'm provided is the above error message and stack trace. Visual Studio breaks on the `Dispose` call, on the `SqlConnection`.

Edit:

The proposed duplicate does indeed point to the correct solution. I don't want to redirect from here automatically, though, because this question garnered better responses, imo. I'd much prefer future readers to see the comments and answer in this question as it was explained much better here.

Comment: A finalizer is not a `Dispose` method. You shouldn't be trying to clean up managed objects from a finalizer; the runtime will take care of that for you anyway. Only clean up *unmanaged* stuff (of which you probably don't have any, and thus don't need a finalizer).

Comment: Could it be this? [Internal .Net Framework Data Provider error 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22962742/internal-net-framework-data-provider-error-1#22963057) - _"Do not call Close or Dispose on a Connection, a DataReader, or any other managed object in the Finalize method of your class..."_

Comment: @cHao: Thank you for voting to close this.

With that said, I'm not calling `Finalize`. This is being constructed by AspNet and a Unity container. I assume it's calling `Finalize`. My `AgentSession` does not have an explicit `Finalize` method and only attempts to `Dispose` the connect.

Could you perhaps explain what you're getting at? I honestly don't know and it sounds like perhaps you see an issue.

Comment: I am sure that you are aware of the Connection Pooling infrastructure built in in ADO.NET. Why do you want to replace this with your own work and spend a lot of time to make it work right?

Comment: _I'm not calling Finalize_ - but you must have a `Finalize()` method, though ..?

Comment: @Steve To my understanding, connection pooling will still kick in when calling `Open`? To be clear, I don't want to replace that. I want to encapsulate the connection within this class of mine, because I need to encapsulate some other stuff, such as a transaction that encompasses all queries called during the connection, etc.

Comment: @Ryan: I didn't vote to close yet. But your `AgentSession` apparently does have a finalizer, even if it's not explicit (perhaps a base class does), and the finalizer is calling `Dispose(bool)`. The point of that boolean is to tell you whether you should clean up managed objects, cause you should only be doing that if someone called `Dispose` explicitly (which, if you're implementing the pattern correctly, calls `Dispose(true)`. If you try to clean up managed stuff, wackiness can ensue.

Comment: I apologize. I, for some reason, was confused by the `Finalizer` name. I did indeed have a destructor. I did not realize that they're actually `Finalize`, etc. So I learned that today. I was also indeed improperly checking the `bool` in my `Dispose(bool)` and was always disposing. The suggestions of everybody here were correct and helped me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mention of `Finalize` suggests that this is an undisposed object going through finalization after GC - presumably you didn't correctly close down the "agent", and it is still referencing an object. In a finalizer, you shouldn't touch **any** other managed objects. Just the current instance (`this`), and any unmanaged external resources. Meaning: you probably have:

```
~AgentSession() { Dispose(false); }
```

and your `Dispose(false)` code is doing something it shouldn't. The other problem, of course, is that you didn't correctly dispose it in the first place.